# How to get the col headers from a select query using psycopg2 client?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have this python3 code :

```
conn = psycopg2.connect( ... )
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute(code)
rows = curr.fetchall()
```

where 'code' has the select query statement

After executing this, 'rows' list will have lists of only the selected row values. How do I run 'curr.execute' in such a way that I also get the respective col headers too?

Meaning if I have say

```
Select col1, col2 from table Where some_condition;
```

I want my 'rows' list to have something like [['col1', 'col2'], [some_val_for_col1, some_val_for_col2] ....]. Any other ways of getting these col headers are also fine, but the select query in 'code' shouldn't change.

Comment: Found the solution :
Use dictionary cursor. First import psycopg2 & psycopg2.extras. Then in the above code change 'curr = conn.cursor()' to 'curr = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)'. Then use 'for key in dict(rows[0]): print(key)' --> which will print all the col headers. Make sure you have the right indentation and that 'rows' isn't an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

you have to execute 2 commands

1. curr.execute("Select * FROM people LIMIT 0")
   colnames = [desc[0] for desc in curs.description]
2. curr.execute(code)

you can follow steps mentioned in https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/get-the-column-names-from-a-postgresql-table-with-the-psycopg2-python-adapter-756